# Content Query Web Part / XSLT Variable Name

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to create my own item style for the content query web part. I need to create a variable to display. The following for title works ...

```
<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

How do I do create the same variable for the Release Date column? The official name for that seems to be ... **Release_x0020_Date**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After your above variable, add a second variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="ReleaseDate">
   <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@ReleaseDate, 1033, 1)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I used date formatting to make it look nicer, you can find other format options here: [Custom Date Formats in SharePoint XSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/).

When you go in to edit your CQWP, select the template you added this variable to (I usually just make a new one, copy and paste whatever template is closest and add this variable to it). When you select the template, you'll see a new textbox for ReleaseDate, input the column name here (e.g. "Release Date;"). The CQWP will display the title and the release date.

Image below shows what I've done, I have the task title for Title (this provides a link to the task display form) and the due date, in my case, below it.

[image: Task with Date in CQWP]